# How can I preserve parameters in closure inside loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am building an array of functions that will be called at a latter time that looks like:

```
callbackArray = [];

for(var i = 0; i < 5; i ++) {
  callbackArray.push(function() {
    console.log(i);
  });
}

for(var i = 0; i < callbackArray.length; i ++) {
  // This will not preserve the value of i
  callbackArray[i]();
}
```

This will print 4,4,4,4,4. But I need a way to preserve the value of i, so that it doesn't keep the same reference, but creates a new local copy of values. The expected results should be 0,1,2,3,4. This is a simplified example to show the problem. However the variable i, should be anything like objects, arrays, functions, or primitives.

How can I do this?

Comment: @Mr.Student, i dont know nodejs but have decent js knowledge. what i am missing ? it works for me check http://cl.ly/image/292D2c3X2i1Y

Comment: what you have does log 0..4 in chrome, http://jsfiddle.net/V7E38/

Comment: What do you want to preserve exactly? The i in the first loop or the i in the second loop?

Comment: Who ever posted the answer with the closure shouldn't have deleted their answer. I will choose that answer if you post it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help

```
var callbackArray = [];

// create a function that returns a new function with "i" properly scoped
var fn = function (i) {
    return function () {
        console.log(i);
    };
};

for(var i = 0; i < 5; i ++) {
    callbackArray.push(fn(i));
}

callbackArray[1](); // output 1
callbackArray[4](); // output 4
callbackArray[0](); // output 0
```

You can also use $.proxy if you are using jquery to achieve the same effect

[See api docs for proxy](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.proxy/)

Comment: Why do you think the OP uses jQuery when the function is tagged `node.js`?

Comment: riiight. sorry about that. I guess you can check the jquery git hub repo and see how the proxy function works. @see https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js